# Is There a Way to Display the Rating in the Category List?

Tags: joomla-3.x, articles, category

I really like the native implementation of article rating. I want to display an overview of all the articles including the ratings.

I thought I can activate the 5 star rating view on the category-list but sadly it only displays the hits and author.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to display ratings on the category view; in 3.6.5 and earlier this is done in the voting plugin's `onContentBeforeDisplay` event which forces the display to be at the beginning of an item and 3.7 will allow you to customize the position to the bottom of the item.  So as long as the plugin is enabled and your layout is displaying the results of the plugin event (https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/3.6.5/components/com_content/views/category/tmpl/blog_item.php#L48-L49 for the "blog" category view, oddly enough it seems the "default" view doesn't display the event results) you should get the item's rating.  The plugin is hardcoded to only display the voting form on the article view though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am new to Joomla, and don't understand all you wrote: "So as long as the plugin is enabled and your layout is displaying the results of the plugin event... " ? Can you tell me what to do in the Backend to archive the desired behavior?

Comment: Or is that a complicated way to say that it does not work?